# How to define macro for UIAlertViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8

There are 400 `Alertview` object added as we need in old project so here I want to define `macro` for `UIAlertViewController` in `objective-c` which is introduced in iOS 8.0

Please help me defining it in Constant file.

Answer (score -1):

**Only For Alertview**

```
#define SHOW_ALERT(title,msg,del,cancel,other) \
do { \
UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:del cancelButtonTitle:cancel otherButtonTitles:other,nil]; \
[_alert show]; \
} while(0);
```

**Only For AlertViewController**

```
#define SHOW_ALERT2(title,msg,ButtonTitle)\
do { \
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];\
    UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:ButtonTitle\
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault\
                                                     handler:nil]; \
    [alertController addAction:actionOk];\
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];\
}while(0);
```

**For Both AlertView and AlertViewController**

```
#define SHOW_ALERT3(title,msg,delegate,ButtonTitle) \
    do { \
        if ([UIAlertController class]) {\
            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];\
            UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:ButtonTitle\
            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault\
            handler:nil]; \
            [alertController addAction:actionOk];\
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];\
        }\
        else {\
            UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:ButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil]; \
            [_alert show]; \
        }\
    }while(0);
```

Comment: I guess as category methods on UIViewController it would feel more natural.